# Is there a way to rename the root of my drive in google collab

Tags: python, python-3.x, google-colaboratory

Iam trying to run some shell scripts for training a model in google colab and trying to mount google drive with below code:

```py
from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/content/drive')
```

and this is the folder structure that's created.

[image]

Is there any way I could rename the "My Drive" to "MyDrive" and I am facing a lot of issues while running shell scrips.

Comment: what errors are you facing?

Comment: The file locations would contain a space and it is having issues with reading and writing files, so is there any way I could rename the folder?

Comment: try to put double quotes around the path before using it, using 
'"[path]"' or "\"[path]\""

Comment: I have some variables in the shell script so i cannot do that for everything.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can create a symlink

```
!ln -s "/content/drive/My Drive" /gdrive
```